# Получить значение из div и добавить его в input JS

Tags: javascript, jquery

Как получить значение из div и добавить его в input (value)?

Структура html:

```
<input type="text" name="qty" id="qty" maxlength="12" value="1" title="" class="input-text qty">
        <div class="count-buttons__table">
            <div class="count-buttons__table-tr">
                <div class="count-buttons__table-td">6</div>
                <div class="count-buttons__table-td">12</div>
                <div class="count-buttons__table-td">18</div>
            </div>
            <div class="count-buttons__table-tr">
                <div class="count-buttons__table-td">24</div>
                <div class="count-buttons__table-td">30</div>
                <div class="count-buttons__table-td">36</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Нужно выбрать число из таблицы и подставить его в value у input. Выбор числа по клику на элемент с классом `count-buttons__table-td`

Comment: А какой критерий выбора числа? Нажатие мышки на див или что-то другое?

Comment: @MichaelVaysman по клику на элемент с классом `count-buttons__table-td`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```js
var elems = document.querySelectorAll('.count-buttons__table-td');

for (var i = elems.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
  elems[i].addEventListener('click', myFunc, false);
}

function myFunc() {
  document.getElementById('qty').value = this.innerHTML;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" name="qty" id="qty" maxlength="12" value="1" title="" class="input-text qty">
<div class="count-buttons__table">
  <div class="count-buttons__table-tr">
    <div class="count-buttons__table-td">6</div>
    <div class="count-buttons__table-td">12</div>
    <div class="count-buttons__table-td">18</div>
  </div>
  <div class="count-buttons__table-tr">
    <div class="count-buttons__table-td">24</div>
    <div class="count-buttons__table-td">30</div>
    <div class="count-buttons__table-td">36</div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: круть, спасибо бро

Comment: там только маленькая ошибочка: после i-- точка с запятой не ставят и нет проверки на i>=0  :)

Comment: @MichaelVaysman, сейчас подправим, дело не хитрое, спасибо за указание ошибки)

Comment: Ответ хороший, но что будет если эти div'ы генерируются динамически? :) Мне кажется надо использовать что-то вроде jQuery.bind иль похожего механизма.

Comment: @MichaelVaysman, ну, на случай, если `div` создаются динамически, то в функции, которая их генерирует и нужно добавлять обработку клика.

Comment: Вот! Вот это я имел ввиду: `$('body').on('click', 'a.myclass', function() {  /* do something*/ });` Но это с jQuery конечно...