# Изменить значение в input по клику на кнопки +/- и взять значение из div

Tags: javascript, jquery

Как изменить значение input по клику на кнопки (+/-) и взять значение из имеющейся таблицы если комплектов кнопок и input на странице может быть несколько?

```js
$(function() {
      var countInputs = document.getElementsByClassName('count-buttons');

      for (var input in countInputs) {
        if (!countInputs.hasOwnProperty(input)) {
          continue;
        }

        var butM = input.getElementsByClassName('btn-minus');
        var butP = input.getElementsByClassName('btn-plus');

        var units = countInput.value.replace(/\d/g, '');

        butP.onclick = function() {
          countInput.value = parseInt(countInput.value) + 1 + units;
        };

        butM.onclick = function() {
          if (parseInt(countInput.value) > 1) {
            countInput.value = parseInt(countInput.value) - 1 + units;
          }
        };


        $(function() {
          document.querySelector('.count-buttons').onmouseover = (function() {
            document.querySelector('.count-buttons__table').style.display = 'table';
          });
          document.querySelector('.count-buttons__table').onmouseout = (function() {
            document.querySelector('.count-buttons__table').style.display = 'none';
          });

          var elems = document.querySelectorAll('.count-buttons__table-td');

          for (var i = elems.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            elems[i].addEventListener('click', myFunc, false);
          }

          function myFunc() {
            document.getElementsByClassName('qty').value = this.innerHTML;
          }
        });
```

```html
<div class="count-buttons">
  <button type="button" class="btn ctrl btn-minus">
         <span>−</span></button>
  <input name="" value="" size="4" title="" class="input-text qty" maxlength="12" />
  <button type="button" class="btn ctrl btn-plus"><span>+</span></button>
  <div class="count-buttons__table">
    <div class="count-buttons__table-tr">
      <div class="count-buttons__table-td">6</div>
      <div class="count-buttons__table-td">12</div>
      <div class="count-buttons__table-td">18</div>
    </div>
    <div class="count-buttons__table-tr">
      <div class="count-buttons__table-td">24</div>
      <div class="count-buttons__table-td">30</div>
      <div class="count-buttons__table-td">36</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zj5512a1/1/)

**UPD**

Суть в том, что значения для value можно получить двумя способами:

1. по нажатию кнопки `+` или `-` (соответственно, число либо увеличивается на `1` либо уменьшается) [пример](http://jsfiddle.net/Symphony/ump6oL6y/)
2. выбрать число из выпадающей таблицы (числа никогда не меняются) [пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/796866/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B8%D0%B7-div-%D0%B8-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%B2-input-js)

Comment: А по какому принципу берется значение из таблицы? Нажимаете + и получаете следующее значение, нажимаете минус и получаете предыдущее?

Comment: @dmitryshishkin значения в таблице статичные (постоянные)

Comment: То что значения постоянные я понял. Мне непонятно что происходит если нажимаешь на плюс и минус.

Comment: Все равно непонятно. Если нажать +, то встанет последующее из таблицы значение или текущее значение увеличиться на один? И если кликнуть по значению в таблице, то какой счетчик значений обновится?

Comment: А при клике по значению в таблице?

Comment: @dmitryshishkin обновила вопрос

Answer (score 0, accepted):

К сожалению, предложенный @dmitryshishkin ответ мне не подошел, т.к. возникала странная ошибка - при клике на кнопки `+/-` значение увеличивалось/уменьшалось сразу на два числа...

В итоге, мне подошел этот код:

```
counters = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('.count-buttons'));

    counters.forEach(function(counter) {
        var input = counter.querySelector('.input-text');

        counter.querySelector('.btn-minus').onclick = function () {
            var newValue = +input.value - 1;

            if (newValue >= 1) {
                input.value = newValue;
            }
        };

        counter.querySelector('.btn-plus').onclick = function () {
            input.value = +input.value + 1;
        };

        counter.querySelector('.count-buttons__table').onclick = function (evt) {
            input.value = evt.target.textContent;
            this.style.display = 'none';
        }
    });
```

Comment: Так в примере же нормально работает или у вас в примере плохо работает?

Comment: @dmitryshishkin ваш код работает везде, кроме моего проекта. событие клик почему-то срабатывает два раза (число увеличивается сразу на два) и я не понимаю почему...

Comment: А можете показать, как вы внедрили? Возможно я смогу помочь.

Comment: к сожалению не могу, проект находится локально. и кстати, это magento)

Comment: Весь проект не нужно, только причины HTML и JS

Answer (score 6):

Можно как-то так решить эту задачу.

```js
var Counter = function(counter) {
  // Сохраняем все, чтобы можно было использовать в методах

  // Счетчик
  this.counter = counter;
  
  // Ячейки таблицы
  this.cells = counter.querySelectorAll('.table__td');
  this.cells = Array.prototype.slice.call(this.cells);
  
  // Кнопку «минус»
  this.minus = counter.querySelector('.counter__minus');
  
  // Кнопку «плюс»
  this.plus = counter.querySelector('.counter__plus');
  
  // Инпут
  this.field = counter.querySelector('.counter__input');
  
  // Инициализируем события
  this.events();
}

// Метод отвечающий за вызов слушателей
Counter.prototype.events = function() {
  // Обработчик кнопки «плюс»
  this.plus.addEventListener('click', this.increment.bind(this));
  
  // Обработчик кнопки «минус»
  this.minus.addEventListener('click', this.decrement.bind(this));
  
  // Пробегаемся по ячейкам таблицы
  for(var cell in this.cells) {
    // и на каждый навешиваем обработчик
    this.cells[cell].addEventListener('click', this.changeFromTable.bind(this, this.cells[cell]));
  }
}

// Берет значение из ячейки и ставит его в инпут
Counter.prototype.changeFromTable = function(cell) {
  this.field.value = cell.textContent;
}

// Метод увеличивает значение в поле на 1
Counter.prototype.increment = function() {
  this.field.value = parseInt(this.field.value) + 1;
}

// Метод уменьшает значение в поле на 1
Counter.prototype.decrement = function() {
  // Сохраняем новое значение в переменную
  var newValue = parseInt(this.field.value) - 1;
  
  // Если оно меньше нуля - делаем нулем
  if(newValue < 0) {
    newValue = 0;
  }
  
  // Меняем значение в инпуте
  this.field.value = newValue;
}

// Собираем список всех счетчиков на странице
var counters = document.querySelectorAll('.counter');

// Превращаем в массив
counters = Array.prototype.slice.call(counters);

// Проблегаемся по счетчикам
counters.forEach(function(counter) {
  // И инициализируем каждый
  new Counter(counter);
});
```

```css
.table {
  font-size: 0;
  margin-top: 5px;
}
.table__td {
  cursor: pointer;
  font: 14px sans-serif;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 2px 5px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.table__td + .table__td {
  margin-left: 5px;
}

.table__td:hover {
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
}

hr {
  height: 1px;
  margin: 15px 0;
  background-color: #ccc;
  color: #ccc;
  border: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="counter">
  <button class="counter__minus">−</button>
  
  <!-- Устанавливаем readonly потому что вручную значение менять нельзя -->
  <input class="counter__input" type="text" readonly value="0">
  <button class="counter__plus">+</button>
  
  <div class="table">
    <div class="table__td">6</div>
    <div class="table__td">12</div>
    <div class="table__td">18</div>
    <div class="table__td">24</div>
    <div class="table__td">30</div>
    <div class="table__td">36</div>
  </div>
</div>

<hr>

<div class="counter">
  <button class="counter__minus">−</button>
  
  <!-- Устанавливаем readonly потому что вручную значение менять нельзя -->
  <input class="counter__input" type="text" readonly value="0">
  <button class="counter__plus">+</button>
  
  <div class="table">
    <div class="table__td">6</div>
    <div class="table__td">12</div>
    <div class="table__td">18</div>
    <div class="table__td">24</div>
    <div class="table__td">30</div>
    <div class="table__td">36</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Если непонятно что происходит, почему я использую this, prototype и new, то прочитайте главы «[ООП в прототипном стиле](https://learn.javascript.ru/prototypes)» и «[Методы объектов и контекст вызовов](https://learn.javascript.ru/objects-more)».

Comment: Мне кажется автор не этого хотел...

Comment: А чего? Если не этого, то я не понял задачу.

Comment: Как я понял, ей надо, чтобы по нажатию `плюс` или `минус`  в `input`  добавлялось значение  `class="table__td"`

Comment: По плюсу и минусу увеличивается и уменьшается, при клике на ячейку бралось из ячейки. Там автор добавила апдейт к вопросу, посмотрите.

Comment: @dmitryshishkin спасибо большое. только как можно запретить отрицательные значения в input ? т.е. чтобы при клике на `-` в отрицательные значения не уходило

Comment: Ну значит я не правильно понял ))))))

Comment: @MarinaVoronova нужно дописать эту проверку в методе `decrement()`. Посмотрите, я обновил ответ.

Comment: @MarinaVoronova не забывайте отмечать ответом, если это работает, как надо и помогло вам.

Comment: @dmitryshishkin как сделать чтобы при клике на `-` число не было меньше 1 ?

Comment: @MarinaVoronova я ведь написал выше, что нужно дописать эту проверку в методе `decrement()`. И даже дописал ее, обновив решение.

Answer (score 0):

Задача не совсем ясна.
Если хотите поле ввода с кнопками `-`/`+` и всплывающими вариантами, то вот:

```js
var $d = document, 
    cbsTable,
    callerEl; 

$d.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  cbsTable = $d.createElement('table'); 
  cbsTable.id = 'cbtn-table'; 
  cbsTable.addEventListener('click', onTableClick); 
  $d.body.appendChild(cbsTable); 
  
  let cbs = $d.getElementsByClassName('cbtn-combobox'); 
  for (let cb of cbs) {
    cb.addEventListener('click', onCbClick); 
    cb.addEventListener('input', onCbInput); 
    cb.addEventListener('blur', () => setTimeout(() => {
      if (!$d.activeElement.classList.contains('cbtn-combobox'))
        cbsTable.style.visibility = 'hidden'; 
    }, 150)); 
    cb.contentEditable = true; 
  }
  console.log('Клик по значению вызывает всплывающую таблицу.');
});

function onCbInput(e) {
  let cPos   = getCaretPosCe(this, true),
      newVal = +(this.textContent.match(/\d/g) || [0]).join(''); 
  this.textContent = Math.min(99999, newVal); 
  setCaretPosCe(this, cPos, true); 
}

function onCbClick(e) {
  let cs   = getComputedStyle(this), 
      btnW = parseInt(cs.getPropertyValue('--btn-width')),
      mX   = e.clientX - this.getBoundingClientRect().left, 
      crrVal = parseInt(this.textContent) || 0, 
      newVal = null; 
  newVal = (mX < btnW) ? --crrVal :
    (mX > this.offsetWidth - btnW) ? ++crrVal : null; 
  if (newVal !== null) {
    this.textContent = Math.min(99999, Math.max(0, newVal)); 
    setCaretPosCe(this, 0, true); 
  }
  callerEl = this; 
  showPopupTable(); 
}

function showPopupTable() {
  let tDataStr = callerEl.dataset.table; 
  if (!tDataStr)
    return; 
  cbsTable.innerHTML = ''; 
  let row; 
  tDataStr.split('|').forEach(rowStr => {
    row = cbsTable.insertRow(); 
    rowStr.split(',').forEach(cellValue => {
      row.insertCell().textContent = cellValue; 
    }); 
  }); 
  let bcr = callerEl.getBoundingClientRect(); 
  cbsTable.style.top = (bcr.bottom + 2) + 'px'; 
  cbsTable.style.left = bcr.left + 
    (callerEl.offsetWidth - cbsTable.offsetWidth)  / 2 + 'px'; 
  cbsTable.style.visibility = 'visible'; 
}

function onTableClick(e) {
  let clckd = e.target; 
  if (clckd.tagName.toLowerCase() === 'td')
    callerEl.textContent = parseInt(clckd.textContent) || 0; 
}

function getCaretPosCe(el, fromEnd = false) {
  let pos = 0, 
      sel = window.getSelection(); 
  if (sel.rangeCount) {
    let rng = sel.getRangeAt(0); 
    if (rng.commonAncestorContainer.parentNode === el) {
      pos = !fromEnd ? rng.endOffset : 
        el.textContent.length - rng.endOffset; 
    }
  }
  return pos; 
}

function setCaretPosCe(el, pos, fromEnd = false) {
  let sel = window.getSelection(),
      rng = document.createRange();  
  if (fromEnd)
    pos = Math.max(0, el.textContent.length - pos); 
  else
    pos = Math.min(pos, el.textContent.length); 
  rng.setStart(el.childNodes[0], pos); 
  rng.collapse(true); 
  sel.removeAllRanges(); 
  sel.addRange(rng); 
}
```

```css
#container {
  display: flex; 
  justify-content: space-around; 
  margin: 25vh 10vw; 
}

.cbtn-combobox, 
#cbtn-table td {
  background-color: #fff; 
  font: 16px monospace; 
}

.cbtn-combobox {
  --btn-width: 20px; 
  width: calc(3ch + var(--btn-width) * 2 + 24px); 
  display: inline-flex; 
  line-height: 1.8em; 
  text-align: center; 
  border: 1px solid #ccc; 
}

.cbtn-combobox:before,
.cbtn-combobox:after {
  display: inline-block; 
  flex: 0 0 var(--btn-width); 
  background-color: #eee; 
  cursor: pointer; 
  visibility: hidden; 
}
.cbtn-combobox:before { content: '-'; margin-right: auto; }
.cbtn-combobox:after  { content: '+'; margin-left: auto; }

.cbtn-combobox:focus:before,
.cbtn-combobox:focus:after,
.cbtn-combobox:hover:before,
.cbtn-combobox:hover:after {
  visibility: visible; 
}

#cbtn-table {
  position: absolute; z-index: 99;
  border-collapse: collapse; 
  background-color: #eee; 
  box-shadow: 0 2px 5px 0 #0002; 
  visibility: hidden; 
}

#cbtn-table td {
  width: calc(3ch + 10px); 
  line-height: 1.8em; 
  text-align: center; 
  border: 1px solid #ccc; 
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="cbtn-combobox" data-table="6,212,18|24,30,36">42</div>
  <div class="cbtn-combobox" data-table="5,10,25,50 | 100,,,500 | 600,700,800,900">123</div>
  <div class="cbtn-combobox" data-table="1, 2, 3 | 10">1</div>
</div>
```

---

Плюс вариант, таблица из кастомных "input'ов":

```js
var $d = document; 

$d.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  let tds = $d.getElementsByClassName('cbtn-table-td'); 
  for (let td of tds) {
    td.addEventListener('click', onTdClick); 
    td.addEventListener('input', onTdInput); 
    td.contentEditable = true; 
  }
  console.log('Кнопки показываются при наведении на ячейку')
});

function onTdInput(e) {
  let cPos   = getCaretPosCe(this, true),
      newVal = +(this.textContent.match(/\d/g) || [0]).join(''); 
  this.textContent = Math.min(999, newVal); 
  setCaretPosCe(this, cPos, true); 
}

function onTdClick(e) {
  let cs   = getComputedStyle(this), 
      btnW = parseInt(cs.getPropertyValue('--btn-width')),
      mX   = e.clientX - this.getBoundingClientRect().left, 
      crrVal = parseInt(this.textContent) || 0, 
      newVal = null; 
  newVal = (mX < btnW) ? --crrVal :
    (mX > this.offsetWidth - btnW) ? ++crrVal : null; 
  if (newVal !== null) {
    this.textContent = Math.max(0, newVal); 
    setCaretPosCe(this, 0, true); 
  }
}

function getCaretPosCe(el, fromEnd = false) {
  let pos = 0, 
      sel = window.getSelection(); 
  if (sel.rangeCount) {
    let rng = sel.getRangeAt(0); 
    if (rng.commonAncestorContainer.parentNode === el) {
      pos = !fromEnd ? rng.endOffset : 
        el.textContent.length - rng.endOffset; 
    }
  }
  return pos; 
}

function setCaretPosCe(el, pos, fromEnd = false) {
  let sel = window.getSelection(),
      rng = document.createRange();  
  if (fromEnd)
    pos = Math.max(0, el.textContent.length - pos); 
  else
    pos = Math.min(pos, el.textContent.length); 
  rng.setStart(el.childNodes[0], pos); 
  rng.collapse(true); 
  sel.removeAllRanges(); 
  sel.addRange(rng); 
}
```

```css
.cbtn-table {
  --btn-width: 20px; 
  --td-width: calc(3ch + var(--btn-width) * 2 + 8px); 
  font: 16px monospace; 
}

.cbtn-table-tr, 
.cbtn-table-td {
  margin: 0; padding: 0;
}

.cbtn-table-tr {
  display: flex; 
  line-height: 1.8em; 
  padding: 0; margin-top: -1px; 
  white-space: nowrap; 
}
.cbtn-table-td:first-child {
  margin: 0;
}

.cbtn-table-td {
  display: inline-flex; 
  min-width: var(--td-width); 
  margin-left: -1px; 
  text-align: center; 
  border: 1px solid #ccc; 
}
.cbtn-table-td:first-child {
  margin: 0;
}

.cbtn-table-td:before,
.cbtn-table-td:after {
  display: inline-block; 
  flex: 0 0 var(--btn-width); 
  cursor: pointer; 
  visibility: hidden; 
}
.cbtn-table-td:before { content: '-'; margin-right: auto; }
.cbtn-table-td:after  { content: '+'; margin-left: auto; }

.cbtn-table-td:hover:before,
.cbtn-table-td:hover:after {
  visibility: visible; 
  background-color: #ddd; 
}
```

```html
<div class="cbtn-table">
  <div class="cbtn-table-tr">
    <div class="cbtn-table-td">6</div>
    <div class="cbtn-table-td">212</div>
    <div class="cbtn-table-td">18</div>
  </div>
  <div class="cbtn-table-tr">
    <div class="cbtn-table-td">24</div>
    <div class="cbtn-table-td">30</div>
    <div class="cbtn-table-td">36</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

Код далеко не кроссбраузерный, это только примеры.

Comment: крутая штука! не то что мне нужно, но оставлю в закладках. спасибо)

Comment: Так написали бы, что именно нужно... а то остается только догадываться. Я добавил еще один вариант в ответ.